# winforms in Tablet PC

Tags: winforms, tablet

I am developing an application for Tablet PC environment and using 17" monitor for development when i used the same resolution in monitor still the application is not fitting properly.please help me..

Answer (score -1):

You can use Dock and Anchor property of each control you are using.

[Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908)

Regards